# What are the options for creating an object model that need caching using entity framework and postsharp?

Tags: entity-framework, caching, ef-code-first, postsharp, devforce

I am working with an internet application that has high demands for performance which means that a good caching functionality is crucial for our success.

The solution is built with Entity Framework Code First for the database access and Postsharp for caching. For the moment the model looks something like below.

```
public class Article 
{
    private readonly IProducerOperator _producerOperator;
    public Article(IProducerOperator operator)
    { _producerOperator = operator; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int ProducerId { get; set; }

    public Producer Producer { 
        get { return _producerOperator.GetProducer(ProducerId); }
    }
}
```

The operations classes looks like below.

```
public class ArticleOperations : IArticleOperations
{
    private readonly IDataContext _context;
    public ArticleOperations(IDataContext context)
    { _context = context; }

    [Cache]
    public Article GetArticle(int id)
    {
        var article = _context.Article.Find(id);
        return article;
    }
}

public class ProducerOperations : IProducerOperations
{
    private readonly IDataContext _context;
    public ProducerOperations(IDataContext context)
    { _context = context; }

    [Cache]
    public Producer GetProducer(int id)
    {
        var producer = _context.Producer.Find(id);
        return producer;
    }
}
```

I am NOT fond of having dependendencies in the business objects but the argument for it is to having lazy loading from the cache... for the most. This solution also means that caching is done only once for producer... at `GetProducer`. Normally I would not even consider having dependencies there. The objects should be POCOs, nothing more. I would really need some new inputs on this one. How can I do it instead? Is this the best way?

We also need to resolve the opposite, ie, from a producer that is cached we should be able to retrieve all its articles.

Answer (score 0):

First, i wish to say, there are actually some (one?) solutions that uses entity framework code first in combination with caching using postsharp. Ideablades has released Devforce code first that actually is doing exactly this. That kind of framework actually resolves it all and we can use the entity framework as it is supposed to be used, and in combination with caching.

But that did not become the solution in this case. We went for complete separation of concern, meaning that the business objects only concern went to be only containing the data. The operations classes got the responsibility to fill the business objects.